# Creating a global trigger that listens to multiple tables

Tags: triggers, oracle11g, audit-trail

I want to create a global trigger in Oracle 11g. Which can be used for auditing of around 100 tables. Can multiple tables fire a single trigger. If yes then how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

> I want to create a global trigger in oracle 11g ,which can be used for auditing of around 100 tables

Is there a reason you want to reinvent the wheel? Why not make use of Oracle's inbuilt auditing?

[Oracle Base](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Auditing_10gR2.php) provides some basic info as to how to get started on Auditing:

> Auditing can enabled by setting the AUDIT_TRAIL static parameter, which has the following allowed values.

```
AUDIT_TRAIL = { none | os | db | db,extended | xml | xml,extended }
```

The following list provides a description of each setting:

```
none or false - Auditing is disabled.
db or true - Auditing is enabled, with all audit records stored in the database audit trial (SYS.AUD$).
db,extended - As db, but the SQL_BIND and SQL_TEXT columns are also populated.
xml- Auditing is enabled, with all audit records stored as XML format OS files.
xml,extended - As xml, but the SQL_BIND and SQL_TEXT columns are also populated.
os- Auditing is enabled, with all audit records directed to the operating system's audit trail.
```

To enable auditing to database audit trail enable auditing to db

```
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET audit_trail=db,extended SCOPE=SPFILE;

System altered.
```

Shutdown & restart the db

```
SQL> SHUTDOWN
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> STARTUP
ORACLE instance started.
```

Now to audit `SELECTS`, `INSERTS`, `UPDATES`, `DELETES` by user `cube` do this:

```
CONNECT sys/password AS SYSDBA

AUDIT ALL BY cube BY ACCESS;
AUDIT SELECT TABLE, UPDATE TABLE, INSERT TABLE, DELETE TABLE BY cube BY ACCESS;
```

The audited logs can be brought up by querying `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL`

Further reading:

- [Auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/auditing.htm#CHDJBDHJ)
- [Fine grained auditing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/idm/fga-otn-082646.html)
- [Configuring and administering auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm#BABCFIHB)