# Show all queries coming to an Oracle database

Tags: oracle, monitoring

I need to see all queries coming to database. How to do that? I could not get proper results from a Google search.

Comment: Why the '-1'? This is a valid question.

Answer (score 14):

Enable [SQL Trace](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_Trace) & all the queries coming to the database will be logged.

```
ALTER SESSION SET sql_trace = true;
ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier = mysqltrace;
```

The trace file will be present in the udump directory.

If you want to audit the database, [look at my previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8922198/92837)

Comment: I believe that should be `ALTER SYSTEM SET sql_trace = true SCOPE=MEMORY` to log all activity against the database.  OP should also get familiar with TKProf to format the trace output.

Comment: there is nothing on my udump directory

Comment: I cannot find the `udump` directory. Could you be a bit more descriptive? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If you need to see **all queries from all sessions** for a SHORT window of time and you need a really simple solution, this is what I do. (The above answers will only show you SQL being run in one session, this gives all SQL across all sessions, easily.)

1). Create a temp table to store all the retrieved SQL:

```
-- Fabien pointed out out that 'port may be inaccessible on 10.2 
       CREATE TABLE "MIKE"."TMP" 
       (    "LOOP_NO" NUMBER(10,0), 
        "SID" NUMBER, 
        "SERIAL#" NUMBER, 
        "PROCESS" VARCHAR2(24 BYTE), 
        "PROGRAM" VARCHAR2(48 BYTE), 
        "MODULE" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
        "OSUSER" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
        "SCHEMANAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
        "ACTION" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
        "MACHINE" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
        "TERMINAL" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
        "ADDRESS" RAW(8), 
        "PIECE" NUMBER, 
        "SQL_TEXT" VARCHAR2(4000)
       )
```

2). Run a nasty polling loop in an anonymous block to gather all SQL run on the system, as long as the block is running:

```
declare
begin 
  for j in 1.. 1000 loop 
  
     insert into  mike.tmp
     SELECT j, b.sid, b.serial#, b.process, b.program, b.module, b.osuser, b.schemaname, b.action, b.machine, b.terminal,a.address,  a.piece, a.sql_text
            FROM V$sqltext_With_Newlines a
            join V$Session b  on a.address = b.sql_address
           WHERE A.ADDRESS NOT IN (select address FROM mike.tmp)
        ORDER BY b.sid, a.piece;
  
    commit;
  
  end loop;
end;
```

3). Query to retrieve SQL:

```
select distinct osuser, a.address, a.sid, a.piece, a.sql_text 
          from mike.tmp a
          join (select loop_no, sid from mike.tmp where sql_text like '%anytexthere%') b 
            on a.loop_no = b.loop_no
           and a.sid = b.sid 
           order by a.sid, a.address, a.piece
```

... please mind that this is just a quick way to trap SQL when you are in a "what the heck is going on here?" situation, and you DO NOT have GUI Tools, and you DO NOT have file access to `USER_DUMP_DEST`.

Comment: Watch, you may not have access to column PORT in V$SESSION ; example : on Oracle 10.2 you don't.

Comment: Also, you really want to expand that SQL_TEXT column to much bigger than 64 bytes... Often, yo uneed the full SQL text to make up your mind about what's going on, and have a chance to spot what piece of code sends that query...

Comment: @ Fabien Haddadi -- Thank you much, I edited the answer to reflect both of your suggestions.

Comment: The table 'V$sqltext_With_Newlines' and its column sql_text is of type varchar of size 64 so you can't log more than the first 64 characters of a query, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me to troubleshoot something, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Running XE in Windows here is how I do it to find what  user  is doing.
Start up SQLPlus and run:

```
> SELECT USERNAME, SID, SERIAL# FROM v$session WHERE userName = '<your user>'
```

This gets you two integer values, SID and SERIAL# for your user.  Your user may have more than one session open.
Run this to turn on logging:

```
> execute dbms_system.set_sql_trace_in_session(<SID>, <SERIAL#>, true)
```

Next have your app do some work... 
Find out where the data went using:

```
> SHOW PARAMETERS user_dump_dest
```

And you'll get something like:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\rdbms\xe\xe\trace
where you will find a number of trace logs. The .trc files are simply text

When done, turn off the logging so you don't fill up files or slow your db down.

```
> execute dbms_system.set_sql_trace_in_session(<SID>, <SERIAL#>, false)
```

There you go - happy diagnosing and reverse engineering!

Comment: `ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION' must be declared` on Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0